# Manipulating zipped PCAP files

Tags: python, ip

I have a zipped file full of pcaps, and I'm trying to sanitize the source IP's. I assume stripping the last octet will be enough.

```
import ipaddress

    def strip_addr(ip, b):
        n = ipaddress.ip_interface(u'%s/%s' % (ip, b))
        return str(n.network.network_address)
```

This is what I have so far for stripping the bits, but I am confused as to how I would go about getting the zipped file piped to my python code. I cannot unzip the files and open it in my code. I do not have enough space, the file is too big. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unzip to a file then read this file line by line, sanitize and write line by line.

Answer (score 0):

This processes one .pcap at a time in memory:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

PCAPS_ZIP_IN  = "pcaps.zip"
PCAPS_ZIP_OUT = "pcaps_sanitized.zip"

with ZipFile(PCAPS_ZIP_IN, "r") as z_in, ZipFile(PCAPS_ZIP_OUT, "w") as z_out:
    for pcap_name in z_in.namelist():
        s = z_in.read(pcap_name).decode()
        # sanitize s
        z_out.writestr(pcap_name, s)
```